# Implementing "begin contact" in box2d

Tags: c++, box2d, game-engine, collision, subclassing

I am working on a game in box2d. I have the following code:

```
    for (int contact_num = 0; contact_num<contact_count; ++contact_num)
{
    if (contact->IsTouching())
    {
        // get the colliding bodies
        b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
        b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

        // check if one of the colliding objects is a censor
        bool sensorA = contact->GetFixtureA()->IsSensor();
        bool sensorB = contact->GetFixtureB()->IsSensor();

        // do stuff, mainly handling variables

        }
    }
    // Get next contact point
    contact = contact->GetNext();
}
```

All of this is being called in the update function of my main class (which also contains most of the games variables). The problem is that I want the code to only be called when the two objects **first** collide, because otherwise something like `score++` will end up skyrocketing in value as it gets updated for the collisions duration. I am aware of a "contact listener" class in box2d with the function "begin contact", but there is no good documentation that could help a beginer learn how to implement it. For example, if I add a contact listener to my main class, how do I get it to handle my score, for example, if the contact listener doesn't have access to those variables? Or where do I call "begin contact" in the first place? Sorry if these are obvious questions, but i was hoping someone could clarify these. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple suggestions which hopefully will answer your question:

1. Take a look at [Box2D C++ tutorials - Collision callbacks](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks). Personally, I think it's a great tutorial on using the `b2ContactListener` class.
2. Just make your class which contains the score information inherit from `b2ContactListener`. That way your `BeginContact` method will have direct access to the `score` data. Presumably that'll be your "main" class. Be sure to also notify your `b2World` instance to use this by calling your world instance's `SetContactListener` method with a pointer to the score containing instance (that you'd subclassed from `b2ContactListener`).

If you still need more help with this, please add a comment to that effect or update your question to reflect what remains unclear.

Comment: Once I started looking at "User Data", things started falling into place - for anyone else that has problems with this, I suggest looking at: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/user-data. Thanks for the help! That page is gold.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article.  The author ends with "...somewhere along the way they all seem to end up in bloated routines with a lot of if/else checks to get the right case" when discussing how to tell what type of objects are colliding.  Do you have any other articles that expand on this part?  Or should I create my own Stack Overflow post for this question?

Comment: @DavidVereb Entity management or entity systems seems to be terms often associated with what the author is speaking of at the end of the article I'd linked. There are questions and answers for this issue on StackOverflow and [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) and on the rest of the Internet where one can learn about entity management.  The visitor pattern for instance is an alternate way for dealing with entity types that may be nice and clean or at least nicer or cleaner but I'd say that's ultimately a matter of opinion.